# Vertex creation in Scala gremlin titan graph DB

Tags: scala, titan, gremlin, gremlin-server

I using Titan Cassandra graph DB using scala.
Creating the vertex and edges to the

```
val conf = new BaseConfiguration ()
conf.setProperty("storage.backend", inmemory)
TitanFactory.open (conf)

val graph = TitanFactory.open (conf)
val v0 = graph + "test1"
val V1 = graph + "test2"
v1 ---("test", a→ 20, b → 30) --> v2
```

It is creating 2 vertex and 1 edge which those properties.
My question is,

Next time when i am executing it is creating another 2 vertex with its edge. I dont need to create any vertex with the label is same for the vextex.

Or Is there any way to create vertex with ID , something like this v(test1) instead of random sequence

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Usually you would want to create your own unique property to serve as an ID. From [gremlin-scala](https://github.com/mpollmeier/gremlin-scala) it looks like there are two ways to do this:

```
val vertex = graph + ("A Vertex", ID → "1")
```

or

```
val vertex = graph + "A Vertex"
vertex.setProperty(ID, "1")
```

That way later you can to the following traversal to find this vertex:

```
graph.traversal().V().has("ID", "1").next()
```

**Side Note:** Since you using Titan you would most likely want to tell titan that this property should be indexed and it should be unique. [This](http://s3.thinkaurelius.com/docs/titan/1.0.0/indexes.html#_composite_index) page shows you how to create Unique Indices in Titan.

Comment: Is there any way i can check whether the vertex is already exists or not. Currently i am doing like below `graph.containsVertexLabel("label")` . if not exists create or dont

Comment: There might be a faster way but you could do a quick traversal. `g.traversal().V().hasLabel("label").hasNext()`